# How to group columns by header in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple tables populated in the same sheet, but need them in a single table. How do I dynamically create a single table? The raw data will change, so it needs to accept additional rows as they populate.
[image]
Here is a demo document with the raw data and desired effect.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V8ytyN-qSUW0Wrba7FxmQ242YXSNQ18y6nneEz6bS5g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your raw data should remain alone in its sheet. So first, remove everything you currently have in Sheet1!A12:D, since it will interfere with your ability to write formulas that allow the raw data in A:D to expand downward.

Once you've removed that, add a new sheet. In that sheet, use this formula:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A3:D3;Sheet1!A4:D;Sheet1!F4:I},"Select * Where Col1 Is Not Null")`

The curly brackets allow the formation of a virtual array. Within those curly brackets, a semicolon means "place what comes next below" while a comma would mean "place what comes next beside." Understand that such virtual arrays must keep parallel structure at all times; for instance, you can't place a range that's four columns wide over one that's only three columns wide.

As written, those stacked ranges go all the way to the bottom of the sheet, since there is no row number on the second part of the range (e.g., A4:D means "the range that starts with A4 in the upper left and runs to the bottom of Column D, wherever that is"). By doing this, you are always able to include more data without adjusting the formula.

All that is left to do is weed out blank rows. The outer `QUERY` as written allows us to trim that virtual array to to only those rows where the first column is not empty.